# Reconocer Enter cuando quiero llamar a una funcion o saltar al proximo input en vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Este seria el codigo del cual quiero modificar, para que me tome el enter para avanzar al siguiente input o boton. Sino otra alterativa es llamar a la funcion loginAction al dar enter

Incorrect Email or Password

```
            <el-form-item  label="Email" prop="email">
                <el-input v-model="form.email" prop="email" ref="email" ></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
            <el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
                <el-input show-password v-model="form.password" prop="password" ref="password"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
                
            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <el-button 
                    :disabled="isSubmitting"
                    @click="loginAction('form')"
                    type="primary"
                    ref="sumbit">Login
                </el-button>
                <p class="text-center">No tienes una cuenta? 
                    <el-link type="primary" href="/register">Registrate aqui</el-link>
                </p>
            </div>
        </el-form>
```